# RxJS unsubscribe with id

Tags: rxjs

Upon unsubscribe, I need to call a function with an id that was originally sent in the data. What is the correct way of doing that?

It is a nested observable as seen in below snippet.

```
Observable.create(subscriber => {
    const myData = nested.getData
        .map(x => x > 1)
        .subscribe(subscriber);

    return () => {
        myData.unsubscribe();
        callWithIdThatIsInData({id:123})
    };
})
```

When unsubscribed, I need to callWithIdThatIsInData() with a property what was sent in the nested observable..

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to store your properties which match your filter condition, during the subscription of the nested observable.

Here is an example :

```
const nested = Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

const stream = Rx.Observable.create((subscriber) => {
  const saved = [];

  const myData = nested.filter(x => x > 1).subscribe(x => {
    subscriber.next(x);
    saved.push(x);
  });

  subscriber.complete();

  return () => {
    myData.unsubscribe();
    //Here you have access to your data
    console.log(saved);
  }

});

stream.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Thank-you. That was obvious, but I am new to rxjs. Should have mentioned in question that I was wondering if there is a way to get the data (saved) only once as my id will never change during the streams... don't want to waste cycles. thanks again